# Variation Swatches for WooCommerce - too many variations

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have an issue with [Variation Swatches for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/variation-swatches-for-woocommerce/). My client needs for an item (t-shirt) to have 3 attributes fields.

1. Top material (17 materials - image)
2. Bottom material (17 materials - image)
3. Size (4 sizes - dropdown)

Example - top material (material A) + bottom material (material B) + size (XL)

Now the issue is that there will be too many variations and possibilities.

[I know that I can change the number, but there will be memory issues](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/3711).

What is the best way to deal with this issue?
[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60179/discussion-between-inarilo-and-vucko).

Comment: I Would like to Suggest Best plugin for variation swatches
[WooCommerce Variation Swatches](http://jcodex.com/woocommerce-swatches-for-products-variation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since price depends on the size, and there are four sizes, you will just need four variations:

1. Any Top Material, Any Bottom Material, L
2. Any Top Material, Any Bottom Material, M
3. Any Top Material, Any Bottom Material, S
4. Any Top Material, Any Bottom Material, XL

This will let you select any combination of material and change the price depending on the size selected.